# apps script - copying manually selected, non-adjacent rows and pasting them below each other

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy manually selected/highlighted non-adjacent rows and paste them directly below each other on another sheet ("fight list raw"). With the script below it works fine, as long as the rows are adjacent. If the rows are non-adjacent, only one row is pasted (the row which was selected lastly / where the cursor is in).

Has someone an idea how to manage it?

```
function copynonadjacent rows() {
SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source_sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var source_range = source_sheet.getActiveRange();
var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("fight list raw");
var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
target_sheet.insertRowsAfter(last_row,1);
source_range.copyTo(target_sheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1+":AA"+(last_row+1))),{contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I want to copy manually selected/highlighted non-adjacent rows and paste them directly below each other on another sheet ("fight list raw").`, I cannot understand your expected situation. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, yes of course. I want to copy row number 2 and row number 4. When I select the two rows by clicking on the row numbers and run the script, only row number 4 is copied.

Comment: But if I select rows 2 and 3 (so no rows between them), the script copies both rows. In the destination sheet the rows are pasted below each other without a row between them. I want this the same way, when I copy row 2 and 4. Was that understandable?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I modified your script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following reply,

> I want to copy row number 2 and row number 4. When I select the two rows by clicking on the row numbers and run the script, only row number 4 is copied.

> But if I select rows 2 and 3 (so no rows between them), the script copies both rows. In the destination sheet the rows are pasted below each other without a row between them. I want this the same way, when I copy row 2 and 4.

In your script, you use `var source_range = source_sheet.getActiveRange();`. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Source sheet.
  var source_sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var source_ranges = source_sheet.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  var values = source_ranges.flatMap(r => r.getValues());
  var len = values.length;

  // Target sheet.
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("fight list raw");
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  target_sheet.insertRowsAfter(last_row, len);
  target_sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, 1, len, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the selected rows are retrieved, and copy the values to the target sheet.
- I thought that you use `{contentsOnly:true}`. So, I thought that `getValues` and `setValues` might be able to be used.

#### Reference:

- [getActiveRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactiverangelist)

Comment: wow, it works perfectly! I don´t really understand the flatMap....-part, but it works great. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Kodi Thank you for replying. About `flatMap`, you can see the document at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap . In this modified script, using `flatMap`, the 2-dimensional arrays retrieved by `getValues` are merged as an array including a 1-dimensional array.

Comment: Thank you very much also for your explanation, @Tanaike, and I´ll check this document you linked! Greetings!